Vertical and Horizontal scrollbar in main window in a canvas
I have a code that works with a vertical scrollbar.
Now I want to add a horizontal scrollbar. But I don't achieve to get the right solution.
import tkinter as tk

# Create master window
fenetre = tk.Tk()
fenetre.title("Fenêtre principale avec Canvas et Scrollbar")

# Create canvas
canevas = tk.Canvas(fenetre, width=800, height=600, bg="white")
canevas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
canevas.config(scrollregion =(0, 0, 5, 2000))

# Add scrollbar associated to Canvas
vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(fenetre, orient="vertical", command=canevas.yview)
vscrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
canevas.config(yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)

canevas.create_window((0, 0), anchor="nw")
# Draw a line on Canvas
canevas.create_line(50, 103, 200, 150, fill="blue")

etiquette = tk.Label(fenetre, text="etiquette", bg="red", justify='right')
canevas.create_window((50, 50), window=etiquette, anchor="nw")

# Créez Label 
#etiquette = tk.Label(fenetre, text="Ceci est une étiquette", bg="red")
#canevas.itemconfig(fen, window=etiquette)

# main loop
fenetre.mainloop()


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] if you want tips.

You need to create an additional scrollbar, configure the canvas to support horizontal scrolling, and update the scrollregion to ensure the canvas allows scrolling in both directions.
canevas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 2000, 2000)) 

and add the horizontal scroll bar as additional element.
hscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(fenetre, orient="horizontal", command=canevas.xview)
hscrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
canevas.config(xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set)

